# Issue with javascript using Array.prototype.slice.call

Tags: javascript, arrays, href

I have a "little" problem that I don't seem to find the solution, the thing is I try to get the links from the "a" tags of html and print how many of them are repeated (and it must be done that way). Thanks for the replies and help in advance!

The problem is that I get the following result when I use it:

```
http://www.testlink.com/ repeated 1 times
http://www.testlink.com/ repeated 1 times
http://www.testlink2.com/ repeated 1 times
http://www.testlink3.com/ repeated 1 times
```

instead of:

```
http://www.testlink.com/ repeated 2 times
http://www.testlink2.com/ repeated 1 times
http://www.testlink3.com/ repeated 1 times
```

If i change the array and just use it with for example this:

```
var linksCanArray = ["a", "b", "a", "etc"];
```

It does work as intended, so I supose the error must be in this line:

```
var linksCanArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(linksCan, 0);
```

Here is the code:

```
var linksCan = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

var linksCanArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(linksCan, 0);
    linksCanArray.sort();
var current = null;
var cnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < linksCanArray.length; i++) {
    if (linksCandArray[i] != current) {
        if (cnt > 0) {
            document.write(current + ' repeated ' + cnt + ' times<br>');
        }
        current = linksCanArray[i];
        cnt = 1;
    } else {
        cnt++;
    }
}
if (cnt > 0) {
    document.write(current + ' repeated ' + cnt + ' times');
}
```

Comment: Shortcut: `Array.prototype` = `[]` (`[].slice.call(linksCan,0);`)

Comment: use can simply use [].map.call instead of Array.prototype.map.call...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `linksCan` collection as well as the `linksCanArray` still do contain `<a>`-DOM-nodes. These might have the same `href` link, but still compare as not equal. The `.sort()` and `document.write` output only work as expected because they yield their `href` when being stringified.

To fix this and work on the strings instead of the DOM elements, use

```
var linksCanArray = Array.prototype.map.call(linksCan, function(el) {
    return el.href;
});
```